# How to reject messages greater than 100 MB HornetQ

Tags: hornetq, jboss-eap-6

We would like to reject the messages being placed in hornetq greater than 50 MB.

Could we restrict it in the configuration at queue/connection factory level.

Placing large messages in HornetQ is causing heap issue and the server is getting crashed.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This should not be needed in correcly designed application. Consider enabling of message streaming on JMS component with  `JmsComponent#setStreamMessageTypeEnabled(true)`. And then make sure you are working with stream based types only, when working with `body` in processors, if you have any.

Comment: The issue should be solved by the answer I provided since that should allow you HQ to discard messages following the address full policy. Any luck? If so, please consider marking it "answered"

Answer (score 3):

Edit your .xml configuration like:

```
<address-setting match="your/queue/address">
   <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>
   <page-size-bytes>104857600</page-size-bytes>
   <address-full-policy>DROP</address-full-policy>
</address-setting>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/paging.html):

> Messages are stored per address on the file system.
>
> Instead of paging messages when the max size is reached, an address can also be configured to just drop messages when the address is full.

..to do so, set address-full-policy to DROP (messages will be silently dropped).

The above settings are documented at:
https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/queue-attributes.html

While, especially concerning the message size elements: https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/paging.html

Comment: Hi Lorev thanks for your reply. what will it happen if i place message greater than 100 MB size.

Comment: As far as the above, the messages are stored per address in the system (PAGE). Alternatively, you could change the address-full-policy to DROP. That would make the system drop messages (actually rejecting them) which size exceeds the given max-size-bytes.